# How to change the 'marker' position in MATLAB plots?

Tags: matlab

I am plotting a boxplot with mean as a marker point.

Here I have fixed the position of each boxlot as I have to insert another series of boxplot next to the first one.

I can play with the position of boxplots, but I am not getting how to fix the marker points at the desired location (within the boxplots).

[image]

Here is what I am trying,

```
pos = 1.3:1:8.3;  

boxplot(data(2:71,[32,31,30,50,62,85,86,34]),...
    'colors','b','positions',pos,'width',0.18,...
    'symbol', 'bd', 'OutlierSize',4);
hold on  

plot(mean(RF(2:71,[32,31,30,50,62,85,86,34])),'-md','linestyle', 'none')
```

Markers should be placed at `pos = 1.3:1:8.3` same as boxplots.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place your markers at *specific* x locations you will need to explicitly put them there because by default, MATLAB will use `1:numel(y)` as the default x locations if only the y values are provided.

```
pos = 1.3:1:8.3;
plot(pos, mean(RF(2:71,[32,31,30,50,62,85,86,34])),'-md','linestyle', 'none')
```

Comment: Thanks It worked, I was putting `pos' in the last, however, it was required to be used first.